# What is `useState(null)[1]` in React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks now. I've seen `useState(null)[1]` but I forgot where I seen it.

I wonder what's different from `useState(null)`?

Comment: `[1]` is how you reference the element at index `1` in an array.  So... it's different in that it's referencing an element in the returned array instead of the whole array.

Comment: That is extraction of an element in an array returned by `useState(null)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), it says

> Returns a stateful value, and a function to update it.

But what they mean is

> Returns **an array** where the **first position** is a stateful value, and the **second position** is a function to update it.

The [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook returns an array where the first position (index 0) is the state and the second position (index 1) is the setter for that state.

So when using `useState(null)[1]` you are only getting the setter for that state.

When you do

```
 const [state, setState] = useState(null)
```

What you are doing is called [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

And because in most cases you want to have both `state` and `setState`, destructuring makes it much easier to use than doing.

```
const hook = useState(null)
const state = hook[0]
const setState = hook[1]
```

With destructuring, you can make that with only one line which is much cleaner

And if you only want the setter, you can do it by

```
const setState = useState(null)[1] // only getting the setter
```

Just keep in mind that **both are the same thing**.

---

> I wonder what's different from useState(null)?

`useState(null)` returns an array (`[state, setState]`)

`useState(null)[1]` is accessing the returned array (`setState`)

Comment: Oh, that's helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The next expressions are equivalent:

```
const [, setState] = useState(null); // Destructuring assignment
const setState = useState(null)[1]; // Array index excess.
```

As `useState` returns an array of values, you can [unpack values from the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Also, you can access ([index into](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)) an array item.

- [`useState` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

Comment: Answer lacks explanation.